# Website -- Google Talkback focuses on elements with no related text to be read

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, wai-aria

I tried to use Google Talkback to access my website on Android today, and I noticed that it focuses on elements that don't have any actual text content. As a result you have to swipe multiple times to get to any element with actual meaning (and in the meantime you don't get any feedback, i.e. the program doesn't read anything). I assume that when using desktop screen reader, it works the same, only you have to press Tab many times.

As a more practical explanation, here is how my site is presented with Google Talkback on. Theoretically every swipe down should move the user to the next element and read the related text. However on a website it selects almost every HTML tag (skipping only divs), so it goes like that:

body (reads the title of the site) -> header -> logo image (reads alt text) -> nav element -> ul element (reads: 'list showing 2 items') -> li element -> a element (reads text inside of the a tag) -> second li element -> a element (reads the text) -> main element -> section element -> h1 element (reads text inside of the h1 tag)...

And so on. As you can see, most of the time it doesn't provide the user with any information, but requires action, slowing the user down (and potentially confusing them too). So is there any way I could manually set only some elements as focusable for screen readers? I couldn't find anything like that on the internet, but it seems that information about website accessibility is generally scarce.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've found that TalkBack works much better with Firefox (from Play store) than with Chrome. My take is that Chrome's accessibility support is somewhat lacking here, and it might be better to advise TalkBack users to use Firefox (if they're not doing so already!) than trying to work around broken stuff in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can set importance of HTML Elements with the [`<role>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles) attribute.

```
<header role="banner" class="site-header">
```

Theese are some of the available roles:

- **banner** – Typically the “header” of your page that includes the name
  of the site
- **search** – For the search form
- **form** - Group of elements
  that as a whole, assemble a form (please note that there isn’t a
  great deal of legacy support for this role)
- **main** – This would designate the main content area on your site
- **navigation** – Use on any navigation list, typically on the nav element
- **contentinfo** – Typically the “footer” of your page that contains information about the parent
  document such as copyrights and links to privacy statements

It’s recommended to label the areas with a descriptive name using aria-label, aria-labelledby or title. This get’s more important in case you use a role more than once. Please note that ‘banner’, ‘main’ and ‘contentinfo’ should only be used once.

Learn more about roles here:
http://a11yproject.com/posts/aria-landmark-roles/

You might also find theese links helpful:

- [The Accessibility Project](http://a11yproject.com/)
- [An overview of accessible web applications and widgets (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/An_overview_of_accessible_web_applications_and_widgets)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already have set ARIA roles. In fact, it now occurs to me that this could be responsible for Google Talkback focusing on otherwise unimportant elements... only that this wouldn't explain why it also focuses on `li`'s which do not have any roles assigned.

Comment: Re focusing on LIs - many semantic elements have implicit or default aria roles associated with them; eg A's with href set have a default role of link, BUTTONs a default role of button, and LI a default role of listitem - more of these in the [Aria in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#recommendations-table) doc. (Generally speaking, you don't need to use role unless it's different than an element's default role.) Role likely isn't the issue here; I've found that Chrome on Android will focus plain DIV/SPANs (no default role) that Firefox on Android and Safari on iOS correctly ignore.